# I need for all my radio buttons with [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting only one of my buttons selected when I only need one. When I click on any button only the last button gets selected.

```
component.html
<input type="button" (click)="someFunction(categoryInput.value)" value="click me too" />
      <div id="categorybox">
      <tr  class="categories" *ngFor="let category of categories">
        <td>
            <input type="radio"  id={{category.categoryName}} [(ngModel)]=selectedCategory name="category" value="{{category}}" (click)=selectCategory(category)/>


          <label for ={{category.category}} >{{category.categoryName}}</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

```
component.ts
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  page= 0;
  home: Home[];
  categories: Category[];
  selectedCategory: Category;
  selectCategory (category) {
    console.log(category.category);
    // do something here
    // this.selectedCategory will be the selected value
    // the category will be the value that was just selected
 }
```

Comment: can you create a stackblitz to reproduce this

Comment: Note that your HTML is invalid; a `<tr>` cannot be the child of a `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code. To point out a few

You cannot have a `tr` inside a `div` tag
You have quotes missing in many of your properties
`input` tags do not need a closing tag
and so on

Assuming that you have categories as

```
categories: any[] = [
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Category 1"
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "Category 2"
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: "Category 3"
},
{
  id: 4,
  name: "Category 4"
}
];
```

your template should look like

```
<table>
    <tr class="categories" *ngFor="let category of categories">
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="{{category.id}}" name="category" value="{{category.id}}" (click)="SelectCategory(category)">
          <label for ={{category.id}}>{{category.name}}</label>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and you can access the selected category in your component class as

```
this.SelectCategory = category;
```

Stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k7fp7v